# total count each day sorted, result grouped by week

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

My query looks like this right now pretty straightforward:

```
select 
    count(*), 
    date(visit_date), 
    DATE_FORMAT(visit_date,"%a") 
from visits 
group by date(visit_date)
```

Here is the result:

http://d.pr/FmMg

what I want to happen is:

1. for each week the count is sorted

Can you modify my query so it satisfies the criteria?

Comment: What defines a 'week' in your mind? Also, would the 'week' count appear next to the incremental count for each day? Give us a sample of what you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you no longer need the count by day and are ONLY looking for count by week:

```
SELECT
   count(*),
   yearweek(visit_date)
FROM visits
GROUP BY yearweek(visit_date)
ORDER BY yearweek(visit_date) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do like this?
- you can use **Datepart** to get **week number** and sort by that.

```
select
    count(*),
    date(visit_date),
    DATE_FORMAT(visit_date,"%a")
from
    visits
group by
    date(visit_date)
order by 
    datepart(yyyy,visit_date),
    datepart(wk,visit_date),
    count(*)
```